# Linked PDF object is blurry in Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013

Tags: windows-7, pdf, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I am trying to embed a PDF into a PowerPoint slide. The PDF contain a flowchart with some text and graphics. I use the following:

[image]

It inserts a low-quality image (e.g. blurry text) corresponding to the PDF content:

[image]

Is there any way to get a high-quality image or even better to keep the vectoriality of the PDF?

I use Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Picture compression is [turned off](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/powerpoint-help/turn-off-picture-compression-HA010355184.aspx):

> - Click the File tab.
> - Under Help, click Options, and then click Advanced.
> - Next to Image Size and Quality, click the file that you want to turn off picture compression for.
> - Under Image Size and Quality, select the Do not compress images in file check box.

[image]

---

The original PDF before it gets inserted into Microsoft PowerPoint (all graphics and text are vectorial):

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.